# Python, Selenium and Chromedriver - endless loop using find_element_by_id causes CPU problem

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, cpu-usage

Good day to all! I've been experiencing this problem for a week now but I don't think I can solve it and I also do not see any solution based on articles online. Hopefully someone can help me here...

**My scenario:**
I need to monitor prices from 6 different tables in one page that changes almost every second. By end of day, I would close the browser (by pressing the X button) and terminate the script (by pressing Control+C) then run again in the morning and let it run through out the day. The script is written in python and is using selenium to read the prices. The browser I use is Chrome. My OS is Windows 2008 R2; Selenium version is 3.14.1

here is partial part of the code. It is just plainly reading the prices within the tables using **find_elements_by_id** inside an infinite loop with 1 second interval.

```
While True:
    close1 = float(browser.find_element_by_id('bnaBox1').find_elements_by_id('lastprc1')[0].text.encode('ascii','ignore'))
    close2 = float(browser.find_element_by_id('bnaBox2').find_elements_by_id('lastprc2')[0].text.encode('ascii','ignore'))
    close3 = float(browser.find_element_by_id('bnaBox3').find_elements_by_id('lastprc3')[0].text.encode('ascii','ignore'))
    close4 = float(browser.find_element_by_id('bnaBox4').find_elements_by_id('lastprc4')[0].text.encode('ascii','ignore'))
    close5 = float(browser.find_element_by_id('bnaBox5').find_elements_by_id('lastprc5')[0].text.encode('ascii','ignore'))
    close6 = float(browser.find_element_by_id('bnaBox6').find_elements_by_id('lastprc6')[0].text.encode('ascii','ignore'))
    time.sleep(1)
...
```

During the first few minutes of the run, the scripts consumes minimal amount of CPU (approx 20~30 percent) but after few more minutes, consumption slowly shoots up to 100%! There is no other processes running in the machine than the script.

**Troubleshooting I've done so far** (they all did not solve my issue)

- upgraded my chrome to latest version - v71 and chromerdriver 2.44
- rolled back Chrome to previous versions (v62, v68, v69, v70)
- rolled back Chromedriver version to 2.42 and 2.43
- cleared my %TEMP% files -
- rebooted machine (multiple times)

The program only gets values within tables but I suspect that somewhere in the background, as the the script runs, unnecessary data is piling-up which causes the CPU to hit the ceiling.

Hoping that someone can help me figure out what causes this problem in the CPU and resolve the issue.

Comment: in Task Manager what app that use high CPU?

Comment: Chrome.exe are on the top of Task Manager that consume most of the cpu.. they consume around 30 ~ 50 percent.

Answer (score 3):

It would be tough to guess the exact reason of **100% CPU Usage** without any visibility to your code blocks specifically the *WebDriver* configuration. So the answer will be pretty much based on *generic guidelines* as follows:

- Never *close the browser (by pressing the X button)*. Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

  - You can find a detailed discussion in [PhantomJS web driver stays in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985008/phantomjs-web-driver-stays-in-memory/45985790#45985790)
- Never *terminate the script (by pressing Control+C)*. Incase there are presence of **zombie** *WebDriver* or *Web Browser* instances you can programatically remove them.

  - You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling/48003289#48003289)
- A couple of useful `ChromeOptions()` and their usage are as follows:

  ```
  options.addArguments("start-maximized"); // open Browser in maximized mode
  options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
  options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions
  options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
  options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
  options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model
  ```
- Using hardcoded sleeps in the form of `time.sleep(1)` is a big **No**.

  - You can find a detailed discussion in [How to sleep webdriver in python for milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451)
- Incase you are using *Chrome* in *headless* mode, there had been a lot of discussion going around about the **unpredictable CPU and Memory Consumption by Chrome Headless sessions**.

  - You can find a detailed discussion in [Limit chrome headless CPU and memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701824/limit-chrome-headless-cpu-and-memory-usage/52680811#52680811)
- Always keep your *Test Environment* updated with the latest released binaries as follows:

  - Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.44**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
  - Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v69-71*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.44 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.44/notes.txt))
  - *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
  - If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
  - Take a *System Reboot*.
  - Execute your `@Test`.
- From *Space and Memory Management* perspective:

  - (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
  - (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.

Comment: The article Free Up and Release... is actually incredibly misleading according to the comments on its own page and https://serverfault.com/questions/597115/why-drop-caches-in-linux
Do not use: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried releasing memory into the loop?
Maybe by picking up the values (list out of the loop?) and then resetting those variables to `None` you can avoid excessive memory consumption.

```
...
while True:

...
    close1 = close2 = close3 = close4 = close5 = close6 = None

...
```

You can also try forcing the garbage collector:

```
import gc

while True: 
...
    gc.collect()
```

If you think that the reason may be a script another another solution to detect the problem might be to enable Chrome to do [remote debug](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) and debug the page.

```
--remote-debugging-port=9222
```

I hope some of this helps you.

Comment: From review: this looks more like a comment, could you please move it there?

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I tried releasing the memory by resetting the variables to None but it did not solve the issue. I will try forcing garbage collector and post update here...