# Firefox spontaneous launch in Selenium

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, geckodriver

Environment:

1. selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar
2. geckodriver-v0.24.0
3. firefox 60.6.1

Everything was set up 6 months ago and everything worked well, the tests passed through the Selenium and there were no problems.

Since **08/23/2019** problems began. Without any launches test inside the Selenium process, started to run spontaneously browsers (firefox)  and did not turn off. 
These processes overload the processor on the server, after which the server starts to brake and also the site that is on the server. These "browser launches" continue until Selenium is reloaded by open browsers after which our automatic tests are blocked and display an error: "unable to create new native thread".

- As soon as one such browser spontaneously opens, the processor load becomes 100%.
- These browser launches occur approximately 1 time in 4-5 minutes.
- All tests are disabled, but Selenium lives its own life, and continues to launch the browsers.

Maybe someone faced a similar problem? Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

---

The launch of selenium occurs on command:

```
su screener -c "/usr/bin/java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/usr/local/bin/geckodriver -jar /usr/lib/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar -enablePassThrough false -port 4444  >/var/log/selenium/selenium_std.log 2>/var/log/selenium/selenium_error.log &"
```

Comment: I don't know if that's the right answer, but when it happen to me, I just run _killall Firefox_ and/or _killall "Web Content"_

Answer (score 0):

Term yourself lucky to have sailed smoothly with `geckodriver-v0.24.0` and `selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar` till **08/23/2019**.

As per the documentation:

[image: geckodriver]

To work with *geckodriver-v0.24.0* you need:

- Selenium Python client version greater then **3.14**
- Firefox client version minimum **57** (which seems to be okay)

You can find the detailed *GeckoDriver, Selenium and Firefox Browser compatibility chart* in the discussion [Which Firefox browser versions supported for given Geckodriver version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403)

---

### Additional considerations

As a part of the best practices:

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u222**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.141.59**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [**GeckoDriver v0.24.0**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) level.
- GeckoDriver is present in the desired location.
- GeckoDriver is having executable permission for non-root users.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v65.0.2*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
  http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

  - You can find a detailed discussion in [PhantomJS web driver stays in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985008/phantomjs-web-driver-stays-in-memory/45985790#45985790)
- If the stale *WebDriver* instances still persist you may require to forcefully remove them.

  - You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling/48003289#48003289)

---

### Outro

[Limit chrome headless CPU and memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701824/limit-chrome-headless-cpu-and-memory-usage/52680811#52680811)