# Is there a way to throttle e2e tests (Cypress) by CPU and RAM? (i.e. throttle Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, testing, cypress, e2e-testing

Writing e2e tests has a problem of potential test flakiness (i.e. tests that sometimes pass and sometimes fail, depending on connection speed, rendering speed, etc). A typical approach to detect flaky tests includes rerunning tests multiple times (that's what Cypress itself [offers](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/cloud/flaky-test-management) as a separate feature). However, I'm running tests for a dApp (using Synpress) and running them multiple times may be expesive. That's why I'd like to explore test throttling, which seems to be a more effective way to detect flaky tests (when writing them).

Cypress has a [simple tool for throttling network](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Throttle-or-delay-response-all-incoming-responses) (using `cy.intercept` + `response.setThrottle`); however, I haven't found any means to throttle CPU/RAM to slow down rendering and computation and detect the corresponding flakiness.

Could you suggest an approach to throttle Cypress (Chrome or another browser supporting Metamask) by CPU/RAM? Is there any way to do this without [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/)? (I mean, in a simpler way, I'm not talking about other contarization approaches, although I'm more concerned about dev performance and "forcefully headless" mode than the necessity to dockerize things itself)

Some related links that didn't help:

- a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50701824/3995261) for Selenium, but they were asking because of high CPU/RAM usage, and the answers don't help with throttling;
- an [approach](https://gist.github.com/jakewarren/477ecd1149abe908cbd5cf7a7c9abaa3) that's supposed to work with some Unixes, but I'm looking for a Windows solution (although may be I'll try it with WSL). [Another one](https://ramesh-sahoo.medium.com/limit-cpu-and-memory-to-firefox-and-chrome-web-browsers-on-a-linux-desktop-c5031480b9f).

Comment: I always argue e2e is not inheritently flakey, as the tests are only as brittle as the code you write. Is your intention here to reduce speeds to improve performance? Is there a reason why the tests cant be improved? This defeats the point of the tests IMO

Comment: @OPSM maybe I was asking the wrong quesion as the dApp I was trying to test has very poor performance and that's mainly because of too many interactions with blockchain which itself is too unpredictable (due to different market conditions). But it's hard to say for sure, and I am no longer working on that project, so I won't investigate whether the interactions with blockchain were the only cause of flakiness. I'll leave the question as is